# Is it possible to lock single modern apps via PIN on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, lock, pin

My customer wants to lock single apps on Windows 10 via PIN; does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What do you by "lock", do you mean, only useable by certain users?

Comment: E.g. locked by system administrator and making users type in a PIN just for certain apps.

Comment: A system administrator can make it possible to only run certain applications with AppLocker, I have not recently researched, if its possible to configure AppLocker to only allow certain UWP though.    Windows does not have the capability to ask for a "pin" before you run an application, you can make it so it requires the user to authenticate Administrator account though.